# MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: .net, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross 5.6.3.
I tried adding MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3.
The output from Package Manager:

```
Package 'MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility 5.6.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'PCLStorage 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3 supports: monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for'DigitalWorkReport.Core'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.2757496
========== Finished ==========
```

Questions:
1.  How can I add MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3?
2.  What is the correct Target Framework for MvvmCross 5.6.3?
3.  Where are the .NET dependencies for MvvmCross defined?

Thank you,
Marc

Comment: What project type are you trying to install that package on? Is it an Android app / library? Or is it a cross platform library?

Comment: It is my cross platform package.  The "...Core" project.  Is this an example of the "bait and switch" design paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` is specifically for Android, it has dependencies on Android's platform-specific libraries. Hence, you should not (and cannot) install it to the .NET Standard library. Instead install it to the Android project only and then install `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location` to all projects.

Comment: So that means my Android project will have both `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` and `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location`?  Or, should your last line say "all **other** projects"?

Comment: Yes, all other projects. You can use `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location` everywhere including the Android project, but on android there is the `Fused` alternative which has some advantages, so you can install this one to Android instead of `Location` package. You can see more details here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/location?scroll=1190#fused-location-android-only

Comment: Hi.  I understand that using `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` is NOT the 'bait and switch' paradigm, but an example of Inversion of Control.  I also understand (I think) that the distinction between a "Core" project and a "Droid" project exists only in VS 2017?  At execution time all of the code is being run by Mono in the Android phone?  So, my question is:  Should I move all my code that deals with `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` into the Droid project?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. Everything will run by Mono, but the reason to have a Core library is that the code within it can be shared across platforms. If you deal directly with classes within the Fused library, you will have to move that code to the Android project. However, if you use only what `IMvxLocationWatcher` provides, you can keep that logic in the Core project and by virtue of Inversion of Control you will get the right implementation of that interface from the Fused library on Android.

Comment: Hi Martin.  I apologize for the slow response: I fell into a wormhole dealing with the Android version of "dll hell".  You may be interested in [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2633#issuecomment-368532014).  I'll close and mark this as a really good answer.  Thx, M.

Comment: Wow, that is surprising. You can alternatively use the preview versions of MvvmCross (prerelease checkbox in NuGet will show them). They should be pretty stable :-)

Comment: I'll give that a try.